# How test method works in Yup validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have the below code, please refer code sandbox link, I am using the yup validation with formik for validating each field by referring to a boolean value that returns from a function.

**So here my requirement is** if the function returns true I don't want to show any message ***and yup should know it is valid*** but if it returns false, I need to show a message "wrong value" and it should be invalid.

**Yup Validation**

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  correctAnswers: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      correctAnswer: Yup.string()
        .test("validate correct answer", "correct", (value, context) =>
          validateCorrectAnswer(value, context.parent.id)
        )
        .required("checking")
    })
  )
});
```

**Function that returns boolean value**

```
const validateCorrectAnswer = (value = "", id) => {
  const expectedAnswer = correctAnswers.find((answer) => answer.id === id)
    .correctAnswer;
  console.log(expectedAnswer);
  console.log(value.trim() !== expectedAnswer);
  return value.trim() !== expectedAnswer;
};
```

I saw some answers but was unsure how to use them via the test method, or is there any other property to achieve this?

Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-sinoussi-kuumrh?file=/src/App.js

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this does the trick.

```
const validateCorrectAnswer = (value, id) => {
  const expectedAnswers = correctAnswers.map((cr) => cr.correctAnswers.toLowerCase());
  return expectedAnswer.includes(value.trim().toLowerCase());
};
```

Your function just needs little improvement. Also when do you fire your validation also needs a fix but you can read up on in it the official docs.
Hope this helps.